# How to add ContextMenu to a button at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

I'm having trouble adding a `ContextMenu` to my buttons at runtime. 
I understand that this is the way to add it to an existing button through XAML:

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Button.ContextMenu>
```

But it should be possible to add it to non-existing buttons, right? I'm adding my buttons based on the data in a file:

```
for (int a = 0; a < File.ReadAllLines(@"bookmarks.txt").Count(); a++) //add already existing bookmarks
{
    index = Array.FindIndex(bookmarks, i => i == null || i.Length == 0); //find closest empty spot in array
    bookmarks[index] = getbook[a];
    book[index] = new Button();
    book[index].Height = 31;
    book[index].Content = bookmarks[index];
    book[index].Click += Button_Click;
    Bookbar.Items.Add(book[index]);

}
```

I'm looking for a handler but I can't seem to find it. So, how do you add a right click menu to a button programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you using Wpf that's the way to do it:

```
private void InitializeItems()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < File.ReadAllLines(@"bookmarks.txt").Count(); a++) //add already existing bookmarks
            {
                index = Array.FindIndex(bookmarks, i => i == null || i.Length == 0); //find closest empty spot in array
                bookmarks[index] = getbook[a];
                Button button = new Button();
                book[index] = button;
                book[index].Height = 31;
                book[index].Content = bookmarks[index];
                book[index].Click += Button_Click;
                Bookbar.Items.Add(book[index]);

                button.MouseRightButtonDown += button_MouseRightButtonDown;

            }

        }

        void button_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
            menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Delete" });

            button.ContextMenu = menu;

        }
```

Hope this helps